# Whitelist IP addresses

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm dealing with DDoS issues on my server. I have created a script that collects all IPs that should be allowed during a DDoS attack, so the list is covered. But, as I'm no expert with Linux, I have no idea how to create something like a module that will be turned on for the specific IP:PORT and allow those IP addresses and drop all other (UDP packets specific).

Also, I have developed a script in python to sniff packets and discover DDoS attacks. So I just need a way to turn the whitelist on.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you considered using software like `fail2ban`? It has many config settings including the criteria for when IP addresses are banned and a whitelist for addresses that don't trigger.

Comment: How large would your whitelist to be? Like, about 10 IP addresses? Or about 100? Or about 1000? You don't have to create a new module for the job, as Linux's `iptables`/`nftables` subsystem is more than capable of handling such a simple filtering. If your whitelist is large, maybe create it as an `ipset` for efficient matching.